# What are the best practices for a many-many relationship?

Tags: sql, mysql

Im wondering what the best practice is for my table layouts to be for a many to many realtionship.

To set the scene we have 2 tables. A table of people, and a table of locations defined as follows

```
CREATE TABLE person(
    id int AUTO_INCREMENT,
    company_id int,
    name varchar(255),
    role varchar(255),
    PRIMARY KEY(ID)
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE location(
    id int AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name varchar(255),
    PRIMARY KEY(ID)
);
```

---

`person` filled with the following dummy data

| id | company_id | name | role |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Jake | Role |
| 2 | 1 | Blake | Role |
| 3 | 2 | Larry | Role |
| 4 | 2 | Mike | Role |
| 5 | 1 | Hall | Role |

`location` filled with the following dummy data

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Company A |
| 2 | Company B |

Currently each row on the `person` table only has one `company_id` associated with it.

Is it possible to have multiple people be accounted for at different locations?

---

For example...

`Company A` currently has `Jake, Blake, Hall`

`Company B` has `Larry, Mike`.

But what if `Company A` and `Company B` both had `Blake`?

Is the proper solution to create a new row in `person` that has the exact same values as `Blake` but just with a new company ID?. This would look like the following

| id | company_id | name | role |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Jake | Role |
| 2 | 1 | Blake | Role |
| 3 | 2 | Larry | Role |
| 4 | 2 | Mike | Role |
| 5 | 1 | Hall | Role |
| 6 | 2 | Blake | Role |

*Note the last row and the addition of an identical Blake entry except for `id` and `company_id`*

or is it possible to have a rolling list in `person.company_id` to query against such that when you run either of the below, `Blake` would show up in both

```
SELECT * FROM person WHERE person.company_id = 1
SELECT * FROM person WHERE person.comapny_id = 2
```

Blake would appear in both results

Comment: This would allow, say, Blake to have 2 different Roles (one for each Location).

Comment: @ScottHunter in this scenario Blakes role at both locations is the same. All info for Blake is identical at both locations except for the fact that he belongs to both location 1 AND location 2. It seems silly in my mind to create an identical row for blake for the only differences to be the location he belongs to. However if this is the proper way to do it then thats not a problem

Comment: A schema that allows you to represent invalid data should be avoided, if possible/practical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An m:n relation in an RDBMS should be modeled with a bridge table (aka association table). And you should be consistent in your naming. Is it a company or a location?

```
CREATE TABLE person(
    id int AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name varchar(255),
    role varchar(255),
    PRIMARY KEY(ID)
);

CREATE TABLE location(
    id int AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name varchar(255),
    PRIMARY KEY(ID)
);

CREATE TABLE person_location(
    id_person int,
    id_location int,
    PRIMARY KEY(id_person, id_location)
);
```

And here are examples how to query the tables:

```
SELECT *
FROM person
WHERE id IN
(
  SELECT pl.id_person
  FROM person_location pl
  JOIN location l ON l.id = pl.id_location
  WHERE l.name = 'Rome'
);
```

or

```
SELECT *
FROM person
WHERE id IN
(
  SELECT pl.id_person
  FROM person_location pl
  WHERE pl.id_location = (SELECT l.id FROM location l WHERE l.name = 'Rome')
);
```

and

```
SELECT p.name AS person_name, l.name AS location_name
FROM person p
JOIN person_location pl ON pl.id_person = p.id
JOIN location l ON l.id = pl.id_location;
```

Comment: Okay, remove the relationship of location from the person table. Make all relationships between person and location occur on the association table. Then when i want to see who works at what location i `SELECT * FROM person_location WHERE id_location=1`, use that result set to then query the person table based on returned IDs?

Comment: Join the tables or use `IN` or `EXISTS` to get the result you want. I've added example queries to my answer.

Comment: that would still leave the possibility tahat a user has two compnies

Comment: @nbk: What are you trying to tell us? Yes, that is what this question is all about. An m:n relation where a company/location can host many people and people who can belong to many companies/locations.

Comment: if role is specific to a location, obviously it belongs in the person_location table, not person.  often association tables have no extra data beyond the pair of ids, but often they do.

Answer (score 0):

this approach lets every user have only one compny and also no duplicatev roles

```
CREATE TABLE person(
    id int AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name varchar(255),
    role varchar(255),
    PRIMARY KEY(ID)
  ,
CONSTRAINT uc_name UNIQUE (name)
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE location(
    id int AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name varchar(255),
    PRIMARY KEY(ID)
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE role(
    id int AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name varchar(255),
    PRIMARY KEY(ID)
);
```

```
create table person_role
(id_role int, id_person int, PRIMARY KEY(id_role,id_person ),
  
    FOREIGN KEY fkperson(id_person)
        REFERENCES person(id)
      ,
    FOREIGN KEY fk_role(id_role)
        REFERENCES role(id)
)
```

```
create table person_location
(id_loaction int, id_person int, PRIMARY KEY(id_person ),
  
    FOREIGN KEY fkperson(id_person)
        REFERENCES person(id)
      ,
    FOREIGN KEY fk_locationry(id_loaction)
        REFERENCES location(id)
)
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/LW5Kcvme)